# How to remove the "Save" button from checkout cart summary form?

Tags: commerce

On the first checkout page (`checkout/xx/checkout`), there is a view which displays line items for the order.  The view appears to be named *"Shopping cart summary (Commerce Order)"*

When I add the standard <kbd>Delete</kbd> button to the view (for deleting line items), it causes a <kbd>Save</kbd> button to appear below the line items.

How do I remove that <kbd>Save</kbd> button?

**Update:**

I tried a form-specific `hook_form_alter()`, but didn't find the <kbd>Save</kbd> button in the `$form` array. It appears to be a form embedded in another form.  Reading answer from @Yogesh made me realize that maybe I had the wrong `$form_id` and can debug with a general `hook_form_alter()` and look for a nested call for the embedded form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing this is implementing [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) and hiding save button. Check example below:

```
function [MODULE_NAME]_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id = 'YOUR_FORM_ID') {
    // Set access to FALSE will prevent rendering form element on form.
    // Check the hierarchy of 'Save' button, before using #access.
    $form['actions']['save']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this with a form_alter hook that I thought was specific to the form and couldn't find the button in the `$form` array. It appears to be a form embedded in another form.  Maybe I should try a general form_alter hook in case I had the wrong `$form_id`.

Comment: Specifically, the form to alter is `views_form_commerce_cart_summary_default`, and the element to alter is `$form['actions']['submit']`.  It's embedded into the parent form (`commerce_checkout_form_checkout`) as _rendered markup_.

Comment: I had $form['actions']['submit']['#access'], so submit instead of save (maybe because I'm using the workflow module)